# Confusion using JWT when calling API

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I wrote an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API which uses the JWTBearer authentication system. This system works well when I call the API from Postman, but I can't figure out how to call it throught my own application or ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Website. Here is the configuration of the API :

**API Configuration :**

In the Startup.cs ConfigrationServices method I added this classical piece of code :

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                };
            });
```

Then I added the middleware `app.UseAuthentication();` to the Configure method.

Now I have a `UsersController.cs` with a `SignIn` method which returns a JWT as string if the credentials are corrects.

Finally, I added a simple `GetUsers()` method with an `[Authorize]` tag to test the JWT authentication as following :

```
// GET: api/Users
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
    {
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Throught Postman, everything works fine. I call the `api/Users/SignIn` url in POST passing my credentials as JSON. I get back my token in response with the 200 StatusCode.

Then I call the `api/Users` in GET passing the JWT previously obtained to the Postman settings `Authorization > Type : Bearer Token`. My API returns a successful code with all the data I asked for. Everything works as expected at the API side.

**MVC Website Configuration :**

To simplify the discussion with the API, I wrote a `Class Library` with a `ClientService.cs` class.

Int the `ClientService.cs`, I have this simplified piece of code which successfully gets the data from the API :

```
public async Task<string> GetPage(string model)
{
    var request = 
        new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            _baseAddress +
            model);

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If I use it, let's say to get the informations from `api/something` as following : `var smth = await GetPage("something")` or any other `AllowAnonymous` method, it will properly works.

But if I want to make it working with an `Authorize` method, I actually add this piece of code just before sending the request :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Where the token variable contains my JWT hardwritten in code for testing purpose. Everything works fine too.

So now I'm obviously trying to avoid hardwritting the JWT. I decided to store it on the client side in an `HttpOnly Cookie` coupled with the `AntiForgeryToken` native function from ASP.NET Core. I wrote this code to store the cookie :

```
private void Authenticate(string token)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        "JWT",
        token,
        new CookieOptions()
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true,
        }
    );
}
```

And now I'm stucked here. Because I use it as a Service, my `ClientService` is the same for all my users. So I can't store the token somewhere and pass it to the newly created client for each request.

I tried to add the JWT to the header before calling the `ClientService` as following :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Request.Cookies["JWT"]);
    var users = await ClientService.GetUsersAsync();
    //GetUsersAsync() simply call GetPage("users") method and deserialize the JSON returned as a List<User>
    return View(users);
}
```

But because my `ClientService` create its own client which sends its own request each time I ask for some data from the API with this code :

```
var request = 
    new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Get,,
        _baseAddress +
        model);

var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

The headers I added before aren't passed to the API.

A simple solution could be to rewrite all my `ClientService` methods to accept a `Token` parameter but it seems redundant and painful.

Which is the best and simpliest solution to pass the token to my API ?

Answer (score 0):

The case you are describing is actually [Cookie Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) :

**1. Sign in**

```
 ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        //Not mandatory: you can add the token to claim for future usage, like API request from server to server
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("token", tokenId));

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        await httpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
```

**2. Add Cookie authentication**

```
   services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            };
        }).AddCookieAuthentication();
```

AddCookieAuthentication looks like:

```
 public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCookieAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false;
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           
            sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts =>
        {
            opts.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
            opts.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
            {
                Domain = "CookieDomain",
                Name = "CookieName",
                Path = "CookiePath",
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                HttpOnly = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            };
            opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

            opts.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
            {
                var authHeader = ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (authHeader?.StartsWith(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) == true)
                {
                    return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }
                else
                {
                    return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }
            };
        });

        return authBuilder;
    }
```

A browser through which the user signed-in will receive the cookie  cookie created in SignIn method and will be able to populate request via client as well.

Comment: This won't add the headers to the class library client request. In order to do that, we have to share the current context to the dll as I stated in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out myself, here is how I solved the problem :

**1) On Startup.cs, add an HttpContextAccessor :**

The Context from our ASP.NET Core website is only accessible by the controllers. The Class libraries can't access it.

To make it available to a class library, we need to use an HttPContextAccessor. It's a service we can use as a dependancy injection to our class library. We just have to add

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method from the `Startup.cs`.

**2) Adapt the Class Library**

The `ClientService` needs to be able to receive the Dependancy Injection as following :

```
public class ClientService : IClientService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly string _baseAddress = $@"https://localhost:[PORT]/api/";

    public ClientService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
}
```

Now we can access the current context from the `HttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor` variable.

Next we have to modify our `GetPage(string model)` method :

```
public async Task<string> GetPage(string model)
{
    var request = 
        new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            _baseAddress +
            model);

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    
    var authorization = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Authorization").Value.FirstOrDefault();

    if(authorization != null)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorization);
    }
    
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The code added will try to get the "Authorization" header from the request and if it's not null, we add it to our own request. This allows the request to the API with the JWT.

**3) Add a middleware to add the JWT to each request**

Now the final step is to add the JWT to each request from our ASP.NET Core application. If needed, the JWT will be consumed by our Class Library without changing any piece of code, either from the library or from the application.

In order to realise that, we have to add a middleware to the `Startup.cs > Configure()` method.

The middleware looks like that :

```
// Add header:
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var jwt = context.Request.Cookies["JWT"];

    if(jwt != null)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
    }

    return next.Invoke();
});
```

This just reads the Cookie from the request headers and if the JWT HttpOnly Cookie isn't null, we add the token to our request. This request will then be captured by our Class Library in order to use it to talk with the API.

A few things to note :

1. Adding the JWT to each request even if we don't need it could consume more bandwidth overtime. It could be also less safe (I'm not a security expert)
2. Adding the JWT to our main request, then create a local client with its own request in our class library seems not optimal. But it works as expected and I'm actually unaware of how to optimize it.

Feel free to point any issue in my solution or modify it to add some clarifications or even other more efficient ways to achieve it.